# Can't type ~ in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux

A couple of days ago i stopped being able to type '~' in some linux terminal emulators (Konsole and kitty, it works in xterm though). Im using Arch linux so when it suddenly stopped I figured it was because of a system updated, so i went ahead and downgraded konsole to an older release, but the problem persisted.

I had a similar problem when I first installed arch because my locales were set up incorrectly, installing the locales correctly fixed the problem but I haven't touched the locales in months so that is probably not the issue either. However running konsole with `LC_ALL=C` lets me type '~' into the terminal so it might actually be a problem with the locales. When I first had this issue `locale` gave me error messages but it doesn't now.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/vsjoqvist/en_SE) custom locale if it matters, but as I said, it used to work fine.

Does anyone know how I would be able to fix this?

edit: When I added Swedish as a backup language most of my programs are now in Swedish, but konsole is still using English for its buttons, this leads me to believe that the English locale is somehow failing.

Comment: As you state, since "LC_ALL=C lets me type '~' ," then it  certainly *is* an issue with the locale, or with an additional keyboard layout. If you've added a keyboard layout, check which of them have tilde.

Answer (score 0):

Certain terminals allow for read only mode. which prevents typing on the terminal. On your terminal, if you move your mouse to the screen,  and right click, does a menu drop down ?   If so, is there a menu item that states something like Read-Only ?  if so, and it's got a check mark next to it, (or it's bolder typed).  Try left clicking that menu item.  Should help to fix a non responsive terminal.  Also, did someone press the key combo  CONTROL-s .  That could stop typing.  if so,  CONTROL-q  should break out of a paused terminal.  Just one more thing, and it might be a stretch, did someone or process issue a suspend command to the terminal?   IMHO.

- jimee

Comment: I can type all characters except for ~, konsole is not in read only mode nor is the output frozen (I get a big yellow bar when i press ctrl + s telling me to ctrl + q when i want to unfreeze it)